# Xpages cannot control spacing in form row tables

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

I cannot control the spacing in a form layout in a form table. I want to put some space between each row so things are not so scrunched up. Out of the box it looks like this:

[image]

I have tried adding padding and margins to each individual row, and I have put some code in a CSS Library:

```
.lotusForm tr.lotusFormFieldRow td, .lotusForm td.lotusFormFieldRow {
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
    xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex">
    <xp:this.data>
        <xp:dominoDocument var="document1" formName="PCInventory"></xp:dominoDocument>
    </xp:this.data>
    <xe:formTable id="frInventory" disableErrorSummary="true"
        disableRowError="true" formTitle="Inventory" labelWidth="100px"
        labelPosition="left">
        <xp:this.facets></xp:this.facets>
        <xe:formRow id="formRow3" labelPosition="inherit"></xe:formRow>
        <xe:formRow id="formRow2" labelPosition="inherit"
            label="Serial Number" style="padding-bottom:20.0px">
            <xp:inputText value="#{document1.computerName}"
                id="computerName1" style="width:150px">
            </xp:inputText>
            <xp:message id="message2" for="computerName1" />
        </xe:formRow>
        <xe:formRow id="formRow8" labelPosition="inherit"
            label="Model">
            <xp:inputText value="#{document1.computerName}"
                id="inputText6" style="width:150px">
            </xp:inputText>
            <xp:message id="message1" for="computerName1" />
        </xe:formRow>
        <xe:formRow id="formRow1" labelPosition="inherit"
            label="Office /Location">
            <xp:inputText value="#{document1.computerName}"
                id="inputText1" style="width:150px">
            </xp:inputText>
        </xe:formRow>
        <xe:formRow id="formRow5" labelPosition="inherit"
            label="Check In Date">
            <xp:inputText value="#{document1.computerName}"
                id="inputText3" style="width:150px">
            </xp:inputText>
        </xe:formRow>
        <xe:formRow id="formRow6" labelPosition="inherit"
            label="Check Out Date">
            <xp:inputText value="#{document1.computerName}"
                id="inputText4" style="width:150px">
            </xp:inputText>
        </xe:formRow>
        <xe:formRow id="formRow7" labelPosition="inherit"
            label="Notes">
            <xp:inputText value="#{document1.computerName}"
                id="inputText5" style="width:150px">
            </xp:inputText>
        </xe:formRow>
    </xe:formTable>
    </xp:view>
```

The css I tried:

```
.lotusui30 .lotusFormTable td {
  padding-bottom:10px;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this css to your XPage:

```
tr.lotusFormFieldRow > td
{
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Knut, that works, but I am not sure why it works. I used FireBug in Xpages and looked at the css, and came up with the above (see original question). In the Xpage when I change the code in Firebug in the right column, it works. But when I added the above snippet to my custom css, it didn't.

Comment: The import part is `... td`. It sets the padding-bottom to every single table cell.